# Saving the pattern created by user in android?

Tags: android

I have use used the `Lock pattern library` in my `navigation drawer` project and it works fine but now i want that for each item of `navigation drawer`, it should ask for different `pattern screen` (eg. `1st item 3x3`,`2nd item 4x4`..) and also want to store that pattern individually.

[This](https://code.google.com/p/android-lockpattern/wiki/QuickUse) is the link for the `lock pattern library`.

Comment: Thanks for editing but please help me out people..

Comment: according to the documentation, you could save the patterns in `sharedPreferences`

Comment: i used Settings.Display.setStealthMode(your-context, true); and is working fine if i have same pattern screen for entire project but i want different pattern screen for each items of the drawer and save them differently.

According to doc there is an option of saving the pattern without shared preference  

char[] savedPattern =  dont know what to put here ???

Intent intent = new Intent(LockPatternActivity.ACTION_COMPARE_PATTERN, null,
       context,LockPatternActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(LockPatternActivity.EXTRA_PATTERN, savedPattern);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_ENTER_PATTERN);

Comment: I am using Navigation drawer and i want to display 3x3,4x4 etc for each items of navigation drawer so please tell me what changes i need to do and where ?